# Increasing a nowhere dense set in $\mathfrak E_{\mathrm{c}}$

Tags: gn.general-topology, dimension-theory

Let $X$ be a closed nowhere dense subset of the complete Erdos space $$\mathfrak E_{\mathrm{c}}=\{x\in \ell^2:x_n\notin \mathbb Q\text{ for all }n<\omega\}.$$

Can you always find a closed nowhere dense set $Y\subset \mathfrak E_{\mathrm{c}}$ such that

1. $X\subset Y$,
2. $X$ is nowhere dense in $Y$, and
3. $Y$ is homeomorphic to $\mathfrak E_{\mathrm{c}}$?